# how to run a command for many files

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, for-loop, sh

I have installed a software in linux machine and it is accessible through the command line.

The command is `mkrun` and when i enter `mkrun` in the terminal it ask `4 user inputs` like

```
run_type
run_mode
mode_type
cat additional_file #additional_file is .txt file
```

I want to use the `mkrun` command for many files of a directory.However for single  file i am able to run the programme by executing the

```
mkrun << END
$run_type
$run_mode
$mod_type
$(cat $additional_file)
END
```

But when i am trying the same comand for many files by incorporating it in the loop it doesnot work

```
    #!/bin/sh
    run_type=4
    run_mode=2
    mod_type=3
    for additional_file in *.txt
    do
      mkrun << END
      $run_type
      $run_mode
      $mod_type
      $(cat $additional_file)
    END
    done
```

I think problem with `END`. can anybody suggest me a better solution for the same.

Error is:
warning: here-document at line 12 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `END')
syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: The end word for a heredoc **must not** have any leading/trailing whitespace -- "END" must be the only characters on the line.

Comment: Also, the `#!/bin/sh` [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) must not be indented; the first two bytes of the file need to be `#` and `!` in order for the kernel to recognize it as a valid shebang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `heredoc` is indented, you can add a dash as an option like this and it will suppress leading TAB characters (but not spaces):

```
  mkrun <<-END
  TAB$run_type
  TAB$run_mode
  TAB$mod_type
  TAB$(cat $additional_file)
END
```

---

You can equally try:

```
{ echo $run_type; echo $run_mode; echo $mod_type; cat "$additional_file"; } | mkrun
```

Don't be tempted to omit any spaces or semi-colons in the above command.

Answer (score 2):

By the way you can use array for your `additional_file` to start

Also you can provide function with your commands.

Example with array:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Array
additional_files=('File_1' 'File_2' 'File_3')

# Function
commands(){
    command_1
    command_2
    command_3
    command_4
}

for file in ${additional_files[@]}; do
    commands                      
done
```

Comment: Could you explain please?

Comment: I have more that one lakhs of  additional_files for each one of these i want to apply the same commnad

Comment: You can try to use my example below, just put name of your files in the array and provide commands to the function

Comment: no it doesnot solve the problem